# What does "Due to varying systems layouts HDMI port may or may not be available" mean?

Tags: xbox-360

I am looking at purchasing a refurbished Xbox 360. One of the sites I am browsing says

> Due to varying systems layouts HDMI port may or may not be available

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Doesn't it mean exactly what it says? Some of the much older 360 systems don't have HDMI ports.

Comment: The Xbox 360 Core models, as well as the 20GB Pro models released before 2007, do not feature an HDMI port. They are no longer in production, however.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says. Basically with a refurbished model, you aren't guaranteed that you will get a specific model - you might get one that is an older model without an HDMI port, or you might get a newer model that has them.

Basically, whoever you are buying this from is basically covering their proverbial butts, just in case you get one without an HDMI port and are like OMG THAT IS NOT AWESOME PLZ MONEY BACK NOW.

Comment: He may be able to message them and request a specific model with a HDMI port. At the very least they can tell him if there is one available.

Comment: What does the hdmi port do? If I don't get one can I not use the Xbox?

Comment: @user52528 It's a preferred method of audio visual display