# How can I tell how large the hard drive is for this Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm looking at purchasing a refurbished Xbox 360. The one I am currently looking at is on Gamestop [here](http://m.gamestop.com/Catalog/Product/107527).

It doesn't seem to list how large the hard drive is however. Is there a way to tell? Or can I add another hard drive (20Gb) to it?

Comment: I would call the store that has this thing in store and ask them...

Comment: You can buy up to 250GB HDDs for the Xbox 360 (maybe even 500GB?). You'll have to buy the right model, however.

Comment: Based on your [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125227/what-does-this-mean-due-to-varying-systems-layouts-hdmi-port-may-or-may-not-be-a) it sounds like the listing for refurbished models does not guarantee a specific model; so no guarantee on HDMI, and no hard drive info.

Comment: Adding onto this, you can also use a thumb drive or a USB stick (two max) up to 32 GB. More info [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive).

Answer (score 0):

This particular unit looks to be refurbished and since no hard drive is listed it may very well be a refurbed Xbox 360 Elite w/o hard drive. It's difficult to tell from the listing but since its a refurbed and xbox did have a no hard drive/memory unit only model it could be the Xbox 360 Phat Console. Hard drives on the Phat consoles (yes I use ph) could be swapped and switched and replaced with larger hard drive up to a 320GB Hard Drive (officially supported drive maximum for Phat consoles).